# Upload a image to User table in Parse Cloud in Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I want to upload a image like profile picture to the Parse cloud with parallel a username, email and password in android login window. Is this possible? or need to make a separate table for image upload? this is my code for new user save.

```
            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) registerPic.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profile.png", image);

            file.saveInBackground();


            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setPassword(pword);
            user.put("UserRPassword", repword);
            user.setEmail(email);

            user.saveInBackground();

            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
```

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow - would you edit it to show what research you have, and any code you have tried? We need a great deal more information to be able to usefully help.

Comment: I already add the users to the user table bt not image to the table. What to do next? @halfer

Comment: Without code or research _in the question_, I've no idea. What language are you using - JavaScript?

Comment: i edit my code and i want to add image at the same time @halfer

Comment: I don't use Java or Android, but there is now some substance for people to answer. I've retagged it to get more people to see it. Have you looked at the parse.com manual to see how to upload blob types?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have done the needful. But you haven't set the file in the user object. So what you have to do is , along with other data setting add `user.put("profilepic", file);`.

Refer [Parse Documentation on Files](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#files) for more details.